# File Based Memory Pool - Is it Possible?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, memory-management, memory-pool

Whenever a new / malloc is used, OS create a new(or reuse) heap memory segment, aligned to the page size and return it to the calling process. All these allocations will constitute to the Process's virtual memory. In 32bit computing, any process can scale only upto 4 GB. Higher the heap allocation, the rate of increase of process memory is higher. Though there are lot of memory management / memory pools available, all these utilities end up again in creating a heap and reusing it effeciently.

mmap (Memory mapping) on the other hand, provides the ablity to visualize a file as memory stream, and enables the program to use pointer manipulations directly on file. But here again, mmap is actually allocating the range of addresses in the process space. So if we mmap a 3GB file with size 3GB and take a pmap of the process, you could see the total memory consumed by the process is >= 3GB.

My question is, is it possible to have a file based memory pool [just like mmaping a file], however, does not constitute the process memory space. I visualize something like a memory DB, which is backed by a file, which is so fast for read/write, which supports pointer manipulations [i.e get a pointer to the record and store anything as if we do using new / malloc], which can grow on the disk, without touching the process virtual 4GB limit.

Is it possible ? if so, what are some pointers for me to start working.
I am not asking for a ready made solution / links, but to conceptually understand how it can be achieved.

Answer (score 1):

It is generally possible but very coplicated. You would have to re-map if you wanted to acces different 3Gb segments of your file, which would probably kill the performance in case of scattered access. Pointers would only get much more difficult to work with, as remmpaing changes data but leaves the adresses the same.
I have seen [STXXL](http://stxxl.sourceforge.net/) project that might be interesting to you; or it might not. I have never used it so I cannot give you any other advice about it.

Comment: Thanks. STXXL was indeed interesting. Since they are talking about big data sets, I believe they are not using any heap for their allocation. I will check that out. If they didnt, then probably i may have a readymade solution...

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for, is in principle, a memory backed file-cache. There are many such things in for example database implementations (where the whole database is way larger than the memory of the machine, and the application developer probably wants to have a bit of memory left for application stuff). This will involve having some sort of indirection - an index, hash or some such to indicate what area of the file you want to access, and using that indirection to determine if the memory is in memory or on disk. You would essentially have to replicate what the virtual memory handling of the OS and the processor does, by having tables that indicate where in physical memory your "virtual heap" is, and if it's not present in physical memory, read it in (and if the cache is full, get rid of some - and if it's been written, write it back again).

However, it's most likely that in today's world, you have a machine capable of 64-bit addressing, and thus, it would be much easier to recompile the application as a 64-bit application, use`mmap` or similar to access the large memory. In this case, even if RAM isn't sufficient, you can access the memory of the file via the virtual memory system, and it takes care of all the mapping back and forth between disk and RAM (physical memory).